# Tuning S3 file sizes for Kafka

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to understand `flush.size` and `rotate.interval.ms` configuration for S3 connector in depth. I deployed S3 connector and I seem to have file sizes ranging from `6 kb` all the way to `30 mb` wondering if anyone here can help me with suggestions on how to get almost equal file sizes.

Here are my settings: `flush.size= 200000`, `rotate.interval.ms=10min`

We tried rolling our own connector as well based on an example in this git https://github.com/canelmas/kafka-connect-field-and-time-partitioner still we can't get the file sizes to be around the same size.

Answer (score 3):

The S3 Sink Connector writes data to the partition path per Kafka partition and partition path defined by partitione.class.

Basically, S3 Connector flush buffers into the below condition.

1. **rotate.schedule.interval.ms**: if  this time has passed
2. **rotate.interval.ms**: time has passed in terms of timestamp.extractor time

> Note: This helpful clear backlog data lets assume rotate.interval.ms
> and we have 6 hours delay data then so every timestamp passed 10
> minute flush will get delay in a few second in contrary if data not
> flowing it will wait to receive next rotate.interval.ms passed

3. **flush.size**: let's assume data flows quite high and if the message reached to flush.size before points 1 & 2 then flush will get a trigger. In the same time if data size flow low then flush will get trigger based on point 1 & 2

**In case of Time Based Partitioner**

4. **partition.duration.ms**: Defines the maximum time flush to s3 within a single encoded partition directory.

Comment: If you're using a time based partitioner, there's also the partition interval window for when files are flushed

Comment: This answer does not address the issue of files being extremely granular down to single-digit kB sizes despite the settings dictating a 10 minute window. If all these settings set _maximums_ and there is no way to limit the lower bounds it would be helpful to know why.